Databricks Compute Optimization

AWS Databricks
Runtime 15.4 LTS

I have been tasked with migrating data from an existing delta table to a new one.  This is massive data (20 - 30 terabytes per day).  The source and target table are partitioned by date.  I am looping through each date, querying the source, and writing to the target.
Currently, the code is a SQL command wrapped in a spark.sql() function:
insert into <target_table>
    select *
    from
    <source_table>
    where event_date = '{date}'
    and <non-partition column> in (<values>)

In the spark UI, I can see the worker nodes are all near 100% CPU utilization but only about 10-15% memory usage.
There is a very low amount of shuffle reads/writes over time (~30KB).
The write to the new table seems to be the major bottleneck with 83,137 queued tasks but only 65 active tasks at any given moment.
The process is I/O bound overall, with about 8.68 MB/s of writes.
I "think" I should reconfigure the compute to:

storage-optimized (delta cache accelerated) compute.  However, there are some minor transformations happening like converting a field to the new variant data type so should I use a general purpose compute type?
lower the instance size and double the node count since I need more CPU but not RAM, and the workload seems to be well-distributed with low shuffle size
Choose a different instance category but the options are confusing to me.  Like, when does i4i perform better than i3?

But I also think there could be some code optimization:

Select the source table into a dataframe and .repartition() it to the date partition field before writing
Change the compute config to support more active tasks (although not sure how to do this)

However, looking for someone else's expertise.

Try  COPY_INTO .
It's efficient and Idempotent and lot of knobs to tweak.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html

Spark UI output will help.
Apart from this, I feel the i4i instance has better I/O latency and Delta Cache accelerated compute will be helpful as you do some minor transformations.

@GaneshChandrasekaran I am moving data from a delta table to another delta table
